# iOS Sticker App: Not Archiving saying unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1 (read description))

Tags: ios, testflight, codesign

(Continuing from title) and failing to upload on the organizer.

[image]

[image]

I wanted to make an ipa file for publishing on TestFlight, but Xcode gives me an error saying:

[image]

[image]

I built by going to Product > Archive. I'm new to this, and I've been creating profiles, Bundle IDs and Certificates for this app. If you know a successful way of uploading a build on TestFlight or creating a .ipa file, please say so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! I tried this on my dad's macbook and it archived successfully! I just put the project on bitbucket, and it was clean from all of the certificates and profiles and took a tutorial on uploading sticker apps and followed it thoroughly. I guess I didn't handle the Bundle IDs properly. (Also make sure your code sigining is correct)